# How does the following commutative diagram within the following proof match the definition for universal property of the kernel and also what is $g?$

Tags: modules, morphism, diagram-chasing

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Definition:}$ (Universal property of the kernel) Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f:A\to B$ a morphism of $R-$modules.  Recall that the $\textit{kernel}$ of $f$ is an $R-$module $\text{ker }(f)$ equipped with a morphism a morphism $i:\text{ker }(f)\to A$ ssatisfying the following $\textit{universal property}$ the composite $fi$ is the zero morphism and for any morphism $g::K\to A$ such that $fg=0,$ there exists a unique morphism $\bar{g}:K\to \text{ker}(f)$ making the triangle

$\begin{array} {c} K\\  
\bar{g} \big\downarrow  \searrow g \\
\text{ker }(f)\xrightarrow{i} A& \xrightarrow{f} & B\\
\end{array}\quad (1)$

commute.

$\textbf{Lemma:}$ Let $R$ be a commutative ring and

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} A & \xrightarrow{f} & B  \\
\alpha\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow\beta   \\
A' & \xrightarrow{f'} & B' \\
\end{array}\quad (2)$$

a commutative square in $\textbf{Mod}_R.$

The restriction $f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}:\text{ker }(\alpha)\to \text{ker }(\beta)$ is the unique $R-$module homomorphism making the square

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} \text{ker }(\alpha) & \xrightarrow{f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}} & \text{ker }(\beta)  \\
i_\alpha\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow i_\beta   \\
A & \xrightarrow{f} & B \\
\end{array}\quad (3)$$

commute, where $i_\alpha$ and $i_\beta$ denote the inclusions.  Moreover, if $f$ is an injection, then so is $f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}.$

> Proof.  This follows easily from the universal property of the kernel.  Consider the composite $\beta f i_\alpha.$ By the commutativeity of square in (2) and the fact that $i_\alpha$ is the inclusion of the kernel of $\alpha$ we have that
>
> $beta f i_\alpha=f' \alpha i_\alpha=0$
>
> Thus by the universal property of $\text{ker }(\beta),$ there exists a unique $R-$module homomorphism $\text{ker }(\alpha)\to \text{ker }(\beta) $ making the square
>
> $$\begin{array}{ccccccccc} \text{ker }(\alpha) & \xrightarrow{} & \text{ker }(\beta)  \\
> i_\alpha\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow i_\beta   \\
> A & \xrightarrow{f} & B \\
> \end{array}\quad (4)$$
>
> commute.  The fact that the unique morphism $\text{ker }(\alpha)\to \text{ker }(\beta) $ is the restriction $f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}$ follows immediately from the definition of the restriction.
> The last thing to check is that if $f$ is an injection, then so is $f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}.$  To see this, notice that if $f$ is an injection, then since $i_\alpha$ is an inclusion, $fi_\alpha$ is also an injection, so the composite $i_\beta\circ f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}$ is an injection, which implies that $f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}$ is an injection.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I am trying to understand the universal property for $\text{ker }(\beta)$ in the above proof.  I understand if I match the information in the proof to the universal property of the kernel and the commutative triangle (1), would i have the following matches: $\text{ker }(f)=\text{ker }(\beta), K=\text{ker }(\alpha), \bar{g}=f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)},$ $f$ remains as it is, and $i=i_\beta$.  But what would the map $g$ be? Basically, I am trying to see how the universal property of the kernel is applied to make the proof of the lemma an easy task. I just have to match the right data from the data in the lemma to that of the definition.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map $g$ in the universal property will be the composition $fi_\alpha$ in $(3)$ and the map $f$ will be $\beta$.  Note
$$\beta fi_\alpha = (\beta f)i_\alpha = (f'\alpha)i_\alpha = f'(\alpha i_\alpha) = f'0 = 0$$
so by the universal property you get a map from the domain of $fi_\alpha$ to $\mathrm{ker} \ \beta$, i.e., a map $\mathrm{ker} \ \alpha \to \mathrm{ker} \ \beta$.

Comment: when using a universal property to justify argument/proof, the portion where it says "if there is another morphism that has the stated property ...", this other morphism has to be make explicit in the argument?  This is the first time I have seen universal properties from category theory being employed in proofs.

Comment: No, a universal property is two statements, and existence statement and a uniqueness statement.  You are free to use just the existence statement to get existence of the map you want.

Comment: thank you very much for that clarification and answering your answer write up.