# Questions about $\text{ker }(\alpha) \xrightarrow{u_1} \text{ker }(\beta)\xrightarrow{v_1}\text{ker }(\gamma)$ in Snake Lemma.

Tags: proof-explanation, modules, exact-sequence

The following is taken from $\textit{Module Theory An Approach to Linear Algebra}$ By: T.S.Blyth

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Exercise 4.5}$ $\textbf{[The snake diagram]}$  Suppose that the diagram of $R-$modules and $R-$morphisms

[image] (1)

is commutative and has exact rows.  Show that this diagram can be extended to a diagram

[image] (2)

which is also commutative and has exact rows and columns. Show also that there isa  'connecting $R-$morphism' $d:\text{Ker }\gamma\to A'/\text{im }\alpha$ such that

$\text{ker }\alpha\xrightarrow{u_1}\text{ker }\beta\xrightarrow{v_1}\text{ker }\gamma\xrightarrow{d}A'/\text{Im }\alpha\xrightarrow{u_2}B'/\text{Im }\beta\xrightarrow{v_2}C'/\text{Im }\gamma$

is exact.

[$\textit{Hint.}$ To construct $d:$ given $x\in\text{Ker }\gamma$ let $y\in B$ be such that $v(y)=k(x).$  Show that $\beta(y)\in \text{ker }v'$ so that there exists a unique $a'\in A'$ such that $u'(a')=\beta(y).$  Show that the prescription $d(x)=p(a')$ is well defined (i.e., independent of $\gamma$) and does the trick.]

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In this youtube video: [Snake Lemma (a VERY COMPLETE proof)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlaGJMOmxTQ&t=668s&pp=ygUYcHJvb2Ygb2YgdGhlIHNuYWtlIGxlbW1h) at the 7:14 mark, the presenter talked about showing the maps $i,j$ are well defined.

But in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802053/how-does-the-following-commutative-diagram-within-the-following-proof-match-the/4802109?noredirect=1#) on a proof about deriving $\text{ker }(\alpha)  \xrightarrow{f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}} \text{ker }(\beta),$

[in that post, $a=\alpha, b=\beta, u_1={f\mid_{\text{ker }(\alpha)},}$ and $u_i$ corresponds to map $i$ in the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlaGJMOmxTQ&t=668s&pp=ygUYcHJvb2Ygb2YgdGhlIHNuYWtlIGxlbW1h) above.] I inquired about the details how the universal property of the kernel is used in the quoted proof.  That proof did not say anything about the need to show the map $f|_{\text{ker }(\alpha)}$ is well defined.  I am just wondering if the sequence of maps $\text{ker }(\alpha)  \xrightarrow{u_1} \text{ker }(\beta)\xrightarrow{v_1}\text{ker }(\gamma)$ need to be shown it is well defined, or is it enough when showing their constructions, simply use the universal mapping property for kernel, and that will be enough.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes you need to show they are well-defined by which I mean you need to show that when you restrict $u$ to $\ker\alpha$ the image lies in $\ker\beta$.

Comment: @feynhat ah kk thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: @feynhat actually after looking at my post again, can I trouble you with about why I need to show why when I restrict the map u to ker $\alpha,$ that it is well defined.  I thought well definedness is associate with maps that sends elements from a set to a quotient set or send elements from quotient set to another quotient set.

Comment: The map $u$ has domain $A$ and codomain $B$. If you claim that this induces a map from $\ker \alpha \subset A$ to $\ker \beta \subset B$ you must show that when we restrict $u$ to $\ker\alpha$ the image is contained in $\ker \beta$. A priori, the image of $\ker\alpha$ lies inside $B$, but we must show that it lies inside a smaller subset $\ker\beta \subset B$ (this will follow from commutativity of the left square). This is what _'well-definedness'_ means in this context. You can't say $u$ gives a map $\ker \alpha \to \ker \beta$ if its image doesn't lie inside $\ker \beta$.

Comment: @feynhat basically in the proof of the snake lemma, to show say that the morphism $\text{ker }(\alpha)  \xrightarrow{u_1} \text{ker }(\beta)\xrightarrow{v_1}\text{ker }(\gamma)$ is exact.  I first need to use the universal property of the kernel to show the existence of the morphism for $u_1$ and $v_1$, then I have to show both maps are well defined?   In a more general setting when showing the existence of restriction map, do I need to show they are well defined?  Or is this only particular to the case of snake lemma?  I mean when I learn about restriction map, i was never told that ....

Comment: @feynhat ... I was never told that I need to show that such type of map is well defined.